# Connected-component labeling with ImageMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Is it possible to perform a connected-component labeling on a image with ImageMagick?

[Connected-component labeling in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible with ImageMagick 6.8.9-10 and newer, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php).

So, if we start with this image:

[image]

we can get the components labelled and also the bounding boxes, centroids and other statistics for each `blob` or `component` like this:

```
convert input.png                                    \
    -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 10%          \
    -define connected-components:verbose=true        \
    -define connected-components:area-threshold=100  \
    -connected-components 8 -auto-level output.png

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 600x600+0+0 296.9,299.6 260033 srgb(0,0,0)
  2: 467x345+70+211 350.1,398.1 53563 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 422x105+56+81 266.5,133.0 34814 srgb(255,255,255)
  4: 105x90+112+310 164.0,354.5 9450 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 178x73+393+246 481.5,282.0 2140 srgb(255,255,255)
```

[image]

You can then draw in the bounding box like this:

```
convert output.png -fill none -stroke red \
  -draw "rectangle 70,211 537,556"        \
  -draw "rectangle 56,81 478,186"         \
  -draw "rectangle 112,310 217,400"       \
  -draw "rectangle 393,246 571,319"       \
  x.png
```

[image]

Comment: How to crop those rects into different files?

Comment: @Sigur If you want ,say. the second blob in a separate file use `convert input.png -crop 467x345+70+211 blob2.png`

Comment: Perfect. Now I only need how to do this automatically from the info saved on external file. I need to cut only some rects, not all.

Comment: Put it as a new question, stating your OS and how the external file looks etc and copy the link to the new question and paste it here and I'll have a look in the morning. Questions, and answers, are free :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try first some ideas. In case of problem, I'll ask, for sure. Regards.

Comment: Is it possible to enlarge a little bit the bounding box before cropping in automatic way?

Comment: Yes. The first two numbers are the width and height, so if you want your box 10pixels wider and taller, add 10 to each of the first two numbers. The second two numbers are the x- and y-offset from the top-left corner, so subtract 5 from each of those. That would give `convert image.png -crop 477x355+65+206 blob2.png` in the previous example.

Comment: OK, I see. But I was looking for some command to do this in batch way. I have more than 1000 files with a lot of components. I suppose tho have some command like `-crop axb+c+d -expand 10px` to expand the BB. Anyway, maybe I can do this saving coordinates and computing within a loop. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can use `-border 10` but that will add a border of your background colour rather than extract more of the original image which may be different.

Comment: Or you can write a simple `bash` script (unless you are on Windows) to extract the crop geometry and modify it.

Comment: Or you could use a morphological dilation to enlarge your objects before doing the *"Connected Component Analysis"* and then apply the geometry from the dilated image to the original undilated image to get the objects at their original sizes on a larger background.

Comment: I'll try the `bash` script. I am having fun learning how to do a script. Thanks.