# How to crop or chop the images at the L shaped corner edges with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

[[image]]

I use imagemagick -6 for conversion.
I have an image like above. Actual image resides in the rectangular area. I need to remove the L shaped corner edges as you see. I tried with lots of options available in : https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#splice . As crop/chop and shave options applicable symmetrical to both sides. I was thinking If I can just splice the un-wanted L shaped areas.
I tried with `convert -background blue -gravity East -splice 10x10 +repage` but of no luck. It basically adds a cross in horizontal and vertical in the middle of the image. Please advise if it possible just to erase/chop a particular area. e.g. some portion of an edge and not the complete edge. The reason here is I don't want to chop-off any part of rectangular shape but the L shapes above and below. Basically looking for removing/splicing with white color just L shaped one corner at a time if possible using Imagemagick-6. As I don't know about the pixel size in advance. I don't know if one liner solution will work.
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to be left with just the large black rectangle at top right that fills round 30% of the whole picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
magick image.png -crop 305x365+232+58 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I mean this for sure. Could you please elaborate more on the offset part 232+58 ? And As I don't know the input file pixel size so I have to use %ge. But surely the offset part will help me to figureout how much the edge I need to remove. The rectangular area can come in left/right/center/top/bottom so. the percentage will surely help us.

Comment: The extracted part is 305 pixels wide by 365 pixels tall starting 232 pixels to the right and 58 pixels down from the top-left corner of the full image. If you put `-gravity southeast` first, you can specify offset relative to bottom-right corner, for example.

Comment: Or maybe you don't know where the image is and want to find it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429090/2836621

Comment: thanks @Mark Sekchell it was indeed helpful. I posted a different question after I realized that would be better to chop the L shapes rather than cropping. As cropping scales symmetrically across height and width.