# Extract small regions from a PIL image python

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgvtT.png)

I have a PIL image in python as shown and I want to extract each of the small red regions separately into a jpeg format. So from this file, I'm expecting file1.jpg, file2.jpg, etc.

How can I obtain each sub-regions in each different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL doesn't really excel at that. I would consider using:

- **OpenCV** `findContours()`, or
- **scikit-image** `regionprops()`, or
- **ImageMagick** [Connected Components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429090/2836621), or
- Python **wand** bindings to **ImageMagick** as above